# SWT nested composite layout issue

Tags: nested, swt, composite

I am new to SWT but have plenty of experience w/ other GUI layout managers.
I have run in to a weird problem when nesting a composite inside of another composite.

[image]

http://www.swooby.com/swt/nestedcontrolproblem.png

If I run the audiocontrol as a standalone bean it works fine.

If I run it nested in another composite it starts to act funny.

When I add this composite to a more complex parent (6 columns), the nested composite does not seem to be honoring its own class defined horizontal span correctly.

The audiocontrol lays out fine in a lesser complex parent (total of 2 columns).

I am using Eclipse Visual Editor to lay these out, so I have not written any of my own code to alter the layout (except to change a Composite type to CompositeAudio).

Code to repro this:
Parent.java

```
package com.twistpair.qa;

import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;

public class Parent extends Composite {

    private AudioControl compositeAudio = null;

    public Parent(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
        this.setLayout(gridLayout);
        createCompositeAudio();
        setSize(new Point(97, 673));
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes compositeAudio   
     *
     */
    private void createCompositeAudio() {
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = false;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = false;
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        compositeAudio = new AudioControl(this, SWT.NONE);
        compositeAudio.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        compositeAudio.setLayoutData(gridData);
    }

}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="36,7"
```

AudioControl.java:

```
package com.twistpair.qa;

import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scale;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class AudioControl extends Composite {

    private CLabel cLabelAudio = null;
    private Button checkBoxRunning = null;
    private CLabel cLabelVolume = null;
    private Scale scaleVolumeLeft = null;
    private CLabel cLabelVuMeter = null;
    private Canvas canvasVuMeterLeft = null;
    private Button checkBoxMuteRx = null;
    private Button checkBoxMuteTx = null;
    private Button checkBoxMuteBoth = null;
    private Scale scaleVolumeRight = null;
    private Canvas canvasVuMeterRight = null;

    public AudioControl(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        GridData gridData31 = new GridData();
        gridData31.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData31.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        GridData gridData21 = new GridData();
        gridData21.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData21.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        GridData gridData11 = new GridData();
        gridData11.horizontalSpan = 2;
        GridData gridData5 = new GridData();
        gridData5.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData5.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData5.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        GridData gridData4 = new GridData();
        gridData4.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData4.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData4.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        GridData gridData3 = new GridData();
        gridData3.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData3.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        gridData3.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
        GridData gridData2 = new GridData();
        gridData2.horizontalSpan = 2;
        GridData gridData1 = new GridData();
        gridData1.horizontalSpan = 2;
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
        cLabelAudio = new CLabel(this, SWT.NONE);
        cLabelAudio.setText("Audio");
        cLabelAudio.setFont(new Font(Display.getDefault(), "Segoe UI", 9, SWT.BOLD));
        cLabelAudio.setLayoutData(gridData5);
        checkBoxRunning = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
        checkBoxRunning.setText("Running");
        checkBoxRunning.setLayoutData(gridData11);
        cLabelVolume = new CLabel(this, SWT.NONE);
        cLabelVolume.setText("Volume");
        cLabelVolume.setFont(new Font(Display.getDefault(), "Segoe UI", 9, SWT.BOLD));
        cLabelVolume.setLayoutData(gridData4);
        scaleVolumeLeft = new Scale(this, SWT.VERTICAL);
        scaleVolumeLeft.setLayoutData(gridData21);
        scaleVolumeRight = new Scale(this, SWT.VERTICAL);
        scaleVolumeRight.setLayoutData(gridData31);
        cLabelVuMeter = new CLabel(this, SWT.NONE);
        cLabelVuMeter.setText("VU Meter");
        cLabelVuMeter.setFont(new Font(Display.getDefault(), "Segoe UI", 9, SWT.BOLD));
        cLabelVuMeter.setLayoutData(gridData3);
        createCanvasVuMeterLeft();
        this.setLayout(gridLayout);
        this.setSize(new Point(151, 415));
        createCanvasVuMeterRight();
        checkBoxMuteRx = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
        checkBoxMuteRx.setText("Mute RX");
        checkBoxMuteRx.setLayoutData(gridData);
        checkBoxMuteTx = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
        checkBoxMuteTx.setText("Mute TX");
        checkBoxMuteTx.setLayoutData(gridData1);
        checkBoxMuteBoth = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
        checkBoxMuteBoth.setText("Mute Both");
        checkBoxMuteBoth.setLayoutData(gridData2);
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes canvasVuMeterLeft    
     *
     */
    private void createCanvasVuMeterLeft() {
        canvasVuMeterLeft = new Canvas(this, SWT.BORDER);
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes canvasVuMeterRight   
     *
     */
    private void createCanvasVuMeterRight() {
        canvasVuMeterRight = new Canvas(this, SWT.BORDER);
    }

}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,10"
```

My other problem was that the audiocontrol initially had the three "Mute *" checkboxes underneath the two VU (left/right) canvases.  In a lesser complex parent the layout was mostly behaving, but the three checkboxes below the VU canvases were not being created.
I used a spy program to browse the running UI, and the controls were indeed not there. The code did have valid objects that I could manipulate.
I thought this was weird, and seem to have temporarily solved the problem by just moving the checkboxes, but I think this could be an indicator that there is something wrong w/ my audiocontrol.

Has anyone seen anything like these two problems? I searched the net and stackoverflow and didn't see anything directly related.

Thanks!

Pv

Comment: Strange indeed. Could you provide some code showing the layout construction only?

Comment: New to StackOverflow, I couldn't find a way to reply, so I just updated my original post w/ a code example.

VE seems a little flakey! :( It was hard to get the nested Composite to show up correctly in the GUI visual designer.
The only way I could get it to visually show up in the editor was to assign a horizontal span value and the CTRL-Z undo the edit...after a few attempts of this it finally started to show up.
Also, VE sometimes fails to save the code and also sometimes writes incomplete code (i guess as the result of throwing some Save exception).

Comment: I did not understand the problem :
I create a small SWT application with your code (without VE) and all the controls seem to be here (on a single grid column).